# ElasticSearch span search over multiple Index over all fields

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch

I am working on a User Interface (HTML + JavaScript) which queries ElasticSearch 1.4
Right now the search is spanned over multiple indexes using the following URL:
http://localhost:9200/_all/_search
But in order to query all the fields I have to send the following JSON in the POST request:
Formatted JSON Data

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "multi_match":{  
         "query":"monitor",
         "type":"most_fields",
         "fields":[  
            "First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "ProductName",
            "Organization",
            "Description"
         ]
      }
   },
   "highlight":{  
      "fields":{  
         "*":{  

         }
      }
   }
}
```

The problem arise because I **don't want to specify the search fields**. I want to ask to ElasticSearch to search on all the available fields of all documents.
Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `"fields":[  
            "*"
         ]`?

Comment: Of Course and it bombs saying Parse Failure [Failed to parse source ...

Comment: How about matching `_all` or do you have it disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally would not recommended running a query against all indexes and fields without explicitly specifying the list of indices and fields since this could adversely impact the cluster performance.

However in case you need to you could try using [query_string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query:

Example:

```
  "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "fields": ["*"],
           "query": "monitor",
           "lenient":true,
           "use_dis_max" : false           
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hi keety, I am aware of but we are building a Google like search over our repository and we do not care about performances but about the results
Your solution is what I was looking for